# Count twurl's retrieved tweets with a specific hashtags

Tags: twitter, endpoint, twurl

In progress from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60369334/5675325), managed to request Tweets from a specific hashtag using the following command

```
twurl "/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#HASHTAG"
```

Let's say we want to know the Tweets using the hashtag "jesus", then we do

```
twurl "/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#jesus"
```

This gives the following JSON

[image: PowerShell twurl]

[Check here the get the full JSON](https://github.com/tiago-peres/stackoverflow/blob/master/json_jesus.txt) (couldn't place it here because question's Body is limited to 30000 characters).

How can I count the number of Tweets retrieved (using Standard search API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, for example you could use jq to filter and count the number of results. https://gist.github.com/andypiper/32bdb4c7f0b8d65385fc7c8fa3988083

`twurl "/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23london&count=100" | jq '[.statuses[]] | length'`

Answer (score 1):

One can count the number of Tweets by going to Notepad++ > Pasting the JSON there > CTRL + F > `{"created_at":` > Count

[image: Notepad++ count number of Tweets]

There's 24 matches, which means 24 tweets.